# Sorting a modified Queryset in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm pull all records from DB and then creating a modified set which is then passed onto the render - this works fine and the added scoring values all all nicely used. Now I would like to sort this modified set but obviously I cannot use the `orderby` statement as the score values are not columns in the table. However, the `.sort` function doesn't seem to exist, when I try in the shell. Now I could manually create a list, but is there a simpler way and more pythonic way to do this?

```
mylist = AboutMe.objects.all()
for record in mylist:

        record.Score = GenerateScoreFunction(weight_factors, myid, record.id)       
return render(request, 'static/list.html', {'list': mylist, 'loggedin': loggedin})
```

The type of mylist is a `Queryset`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sorted()` function to return a sorted list based on a given key:

```
return render(request, 'static/list.html', {'list': sorted(mylist, key=lambda r: r.Score), 
                                           'loggedin': loggedin})
```

Answer (score 1):

The most Django way is to see if you can replace the GenerateScoreFunction with annotate and aggregate functions:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#annotate
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#id5